# SSH access to Linux box behind Microsoft Remote Desktop

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, remote-desktop, git

Situation currently:

To access a remote Linux VPS we need to load up a VPN connection, login to Microsoft Remote Desktop and *then* connect to the VPS using SSH inside the remote desktop environment.

```
[local] -> [vpn] -> [mrd] -> [ssh (putty)] -> [vps]
```

Would it be in any way possible to use SSH as such:

```
[local] -> [vpn+ssh (terminal)] -> [vps]
```

Currently, we're having trouble getting proper code transfers working with the remote desktop system, and instead would like to use `git push` our code changes directly from local setups to the remote VPS which sits behind a VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.
You may ask the network administrator that if the SSH service of the VPS could be opened to the VPN user. If it's allowed, they can set this up.